# forEach en array de arrays no funciona

Tags: javascript, nodejs

mi codigo es el siguiente

```
var array=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

array.forEach(function(indice){
    array[indice].forEach(function(index){
        console.log(array[indice][index]);
    })
})
```

no funciona, porque?

Comment: Que error te marca o especificamente que es lo que no funciona?

Comment: mejor dicho que resultado quieres?

Comment: @aldanux solo es un prueba que hice, quiero mostrar el contenido de cada array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `forEach()` envía como parámetro a la función, el contenido de la posición pertinente de la matriz, no el indice.
Lo que buscas se parece a esto:

```js
var array=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

array.forEach(function(indice){
    indice.forEach(function(index){
       console.log(index);
    });
});
```

Comment: Castellvi me equivoque, y si coloco otro parametro en la funcion del foreach? donde puedo leer mas sobre esto

Comment: Por lo que leo, el segundo argumento seria el indice, y el tercero una copia del array...
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Comment: listo solucionado!!!